error after installing google-text-to-speech
trying to install google text to speech, got this:
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/nix/store/4fn6rij1asjq8r1d3ibhpsl1g70hxs16-python3.10-pip-24.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/nix/store/4fn6rij1asjq8r1d3ibhpsl1g70hxs16-python3.10-pip-24.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/nix/store/4fn6rij1asjq8r1d3ibhpsl1g70hxs16-python3.10-pip-24.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o920ieif/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o920ieif/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o920ieif/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 497, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o920ieif/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
        File "/nix/store/hg8z7jqs9pwg114dh6s34iqrv5aswmrw-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 1139, in getsource
          lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
        File "/nix/store/hg8z7jqs9pwg114dh6s34iqrv5aswmrw-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 1121, in getsourcelines
          lines, lnum = findsource(object)
        File "/nix/store/hg8z7jqs9pwg114dh6s34iqrv5aswmrw-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 958, in findsource
          raise OSError('could not get source code')
      OSError: could not get source code
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

i need help, this is a vital module for my project

What command did you run?

Did you update pip,wheel and setuptools to the latest version? pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools?

pip install google-text-to-speech
